# CSS wrong shadow effect (paper curl) on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, wordpress, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to achieve page curl like this:

[image: page curl]

I've followed this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fpjoa

If I create new *PHP* and *CSS* files and copy - paste code from link above, results are correct, shown as expected. But If I'm using this code for my Wordpress website, It not working with *Internet Explorer*, look at picture below:

[image: wrong paper curl]

As you see above, right corner went wrong. Have you ideas why It happening? Maybe I should change something for *IE*? But why sample from link above working correctly with *IE*?

I'm using css on `page-wrap` -> `content-wrapper` class in following:

```
.page-wrap .content-wrapper {
    position: relative;  
    background: white;/* #f0ab67;*/
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;  
}
.page-wrap .content-wrapper:before, 
.page-wrap .content-wrapper:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 48%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 40px;      
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
    -moz-transform-origin: top right;
    -ms-transform-origin: top right;
    transform-origin: top right;

    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 30px 6px 10px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    z-index: -1;
}
.page-wrap .content-wrapper:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
    transform: skew(5deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

Note: I'm using *Sydney* theme.

Comment: _“But why sample from link above working correctly with IE?”_ – well, because there’s something different on/about your site. But without you showing us your site, or at least a [mcve] that makes the problem reproducible, there is not much we can do for you.

Comment: oh poor you. -1. not from me. take my +1.

Answer (score 4):

How CBroe said, it is difficult without an example. But maybe this solution work for you:

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}

.test:before {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.test:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 12px;
  width: 45%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 19px #aaa;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```